# Check whether a value exists in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the next JSON:

```
var JSONObject = {"animals": [{name:"cat"}, {name:"dog"}]};
```

What is the best way to know if the "dog" value exists in the JSON object?

Thanks.

**Solution 1**

```
var JSONObject = {"animals": [{name:"cat"}, {name:"dog"}]};
...
for (i=0; i < JSONObject.animals.length; i++) {
    if (JSONObject.animals[i].name == "dog")
        return true;
}
return false;
```

**Solution 2 (JQuery)**

```
var JSONObject = {"animals": [{name:"cat"}, {name:"dog"}]};
...
$.map(JSONObject.animals, function(elem, index) {
 if (elem.name == "dog") 
     return true;
});
return false;
```

**Solution 3 (using some() method)**

```
function _isContains(json, value) {
    let contains = false;
    Object.keys(json).some(key => {
        contains = typeof json[key] === 'object' ? 
        _isContains(json[key], value) : json[key] === value;
        return contains;
    });
    return contains;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var JSON = [{"name":"cat"}, {"name":"dog"}];
```

The JSON variable refers to an array of object with one property called "name".
I don't know of the best way but this is what I do?

```
var hasMatch =false;

for (var index = 0; index < JSON.length; ++index) {

 var animal = JSON[index];

 if(animal.Name == "dog"){
   hasMatch = true;
   break;
 }
}
```

Comment: `JSON refers to an array of object with one property called "name"`, how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @JohnP The OP defines `JSON` to be an array of objects.

Comment: @Casey @Vijay apologies, I thought you were talking about JSON (definition)  and not the variable in your code ^_^

Answer (score 16):

#### Check for a value single level

```
const hasValue = Object.values(json).includes("bar");
```

#### Check for a value multi-level

```
function hasValueDeep(json, findValue) {
    const values = Object.values(json);
    let hasValue = values.includes(findValue);
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        if (typeof value === "object") {
            hasValue = hasValue || hasValueDeep(value, findValue);
        }
    })
    return hasValue;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Below function can be used to check for a value in any level in a JSON

```
function _isContains(json, value) {
    let contains = false;
    Object.keys(json).some(key => {
        contains = typeof json[key] === 'object' ? _isContains(json[key], value) : json[key] === value;
         return contains;
    });
    return contains;
 }
```

then to check if JSON contains the value

```
_isContains(JSONObject, "dog")
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ponmudi/uykaacLw/

Most of the answers mentioned here compares by 'name' key. 
But no need to care about the key, can just checks if JSON contains the given value. So that the function can be used to find any value irrespective of the key.

Answer (score 6):

**Why not `JSON.stringify` and `.includes()`?**

You can easily check if a JSON object includes a value by turning it into a string and checking the string.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSONObject).includes("dog"))
--> true
```

**Edit:** make sure to check browser compatibility for `.includes()`, and this approach should be used only when the key names are known to *not* be the search value.

Comment: Be careful with this approach, as it will check to see it's whole useage and will return true in cases where it shouldn't - for example: searching an array of ['10'] for 1 will return turn, when the array doesn't include 1.

Comment: @heady12 question context is for a specific word, "dog" in this question. Also we are not searching within an array, but within a JSON object, and based on the answers, having a consistent key name (in this case "name").

Answer (score 3):

Because the "dog" you are looking for is inside of an array, then you may also use [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which returns always an array of items that much the filter criteria.
If the applied filter returns an empty array then no entries for "dog".

```
const JSONObject = {"animals": [{name: "cat"}, {name: "dog"}]}; // Your array

const exists = JSONObject.animals.filter(item => item.name === "dog").length > 0;
console.log("Exists? " + exists); // Exists: true
```

You may also get a count of how many times dog exists in your array.

```
const JSONObject = {"animals": [{name: "cat"}, {name: "dog"}]}; // Your array

const existsCount = JSONObject.animals.filter(item => item.name === "dog").length;
console.log("Exists: " + existsCount + " time(s)"); // Exists: 1 time(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could improve on [the answer from Ponmudi VN:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42264825/3280963)

- Shorter Code
- Look for a **key** and a **value**

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/solarbaypilot/sn3wtea2/

```
function _isContains(json, keyname, value) {

return Object.keys(json).some(key => {
        return typeof json[key] === 'object' ? 
        _isContains(json[key], keyname, value) : key === keyname && json[key] === value;
    });
}

var JSONObject = {"animals": [{name:"cat"}, {name:"dog"}]};


document.getElementById('dog').innerHTML = _isContains(JSONObject, "name", "dog");
document.getElementById('puppy').innerHTML = _isContains(JSONObject, "name", "puppy");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var JSONObject = {"animals": [{name:"cat"}, {name:"dog"}]};

 var Duplicate= JSONObject .find(s => s.name== "cat");
        if (typeof (Duplicate) === "undefined") {
           alert("Not Exist");
           return;
        } else {
            if (JSON.stringify(Duplicate).length > 0) {
                alert("Value Exist");
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please always describe what you are doing in your answer. It should be updated or removed. Read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before you provide more answers ^^

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/4733879) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

This example puts your JSON into proper format and does an existence check.  I use jquery for convenience.

http://jsfiddle.net/nXFxC/

```
<!-- HTML -->
<span id="test">Hello</span><br>
<span id="test2">Hello</span>

//Javascript

$(document).ready(function(){
    var JSON = {"animals":[{"name":"cat"}, {"name":"dog"}]};

if(JSON.animals[1].name){      
$("#test").html("It exists");
}
if(!JSON.animals[2]){       
$("#test2").html("It doesn't exist");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best and easy way:

```
$lista = @()

$lista += ('{"name": "Diego" }' | ConvertFrom-Json)
$lista += ('{"name": "Monica" }' | ConvertFrom-Json)
$lista += ('{"name": "Celia" }' | ConvertFrom-Json)
$lista += ('{"name": "Quin" }' | ConvertFrom-Json)

if ("Diego" -in $lista.name) {
    Write-Host "is in the list"
    return $true

}
else {
    Write-Host "not in the list"
    return $false
}
```