# Checking if the property exist versus checking if it is null

Tags: javascript

Is it harder to check if a property exists in a JSON object versus checking if the property is null?

Can you do both at the same time?

Comment: Can you be specific?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384421/check-whether-a-value-exists-in-json-object

Comment: If a property is null, then it is `=== null`. If it is not set on a JSON object, then it is `=== undefined`.

Comment: @GOTO0 "on a JSON object" --- http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @zerkms I *really* hope you understand what I mean anyway.

Comment: @GOTO0 It's not me that I worry about but newbies that read such misleading statements and continue spreading the nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hasOwnProperty(prop)` to determine if the property exists.

```
var a = { p: null };
a.p == null; // true
a.hasOwnProperty('p'); // true
```

Comment: You could have mentioned `in` operator as well. `'p' in a`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for checking if a property exists is:

```
if ('prop' in obj)
```

or

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty('prop'))
```

The syntax for checking if a property is null is:

```
if (obj.prop === null)
```

You can't in general do both in a single operation. If the property doesn't exist, `obj.prop` will be `undefined`, so `=== null` will be false.

However, in many cases you know a priori what kind of values a property will contain. If you know that if it exists it will always be a truthy value, you can simply write:

```
if (obj.prop)
```

A common situation where this occurs is when the property always contains an object. We can take advantage of this in idioms like:

```
if (obj && obj.prop && obj.prop.subprop && obj.prop.subprop.number == 3)
```