# Check if zip code in input exists in JSON and get category

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON element with a bunch of different zip codes associated with "zones." What I would like to do is allow a user to submit their zip code, check if the zip code exists within the JSON element and then report which "zone" it belongs to if it does:

```js
var zones = [{
    "zone": "one",
    "zipcodes": ["69122", "69125", "69128", "69129"]
  },
  {
    "zone": "two",
    "zipcodes": ["67515", "67516", "67518", "67521"]
  }
];

$(function() {
  $('#userZip').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userZip = $('input[type="text"]').val();
    // Check if zip exists in JSON and report which zone it belongs to
  });
});
```

```css
i {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="userZip">
  <i>Enter zip code "69122" as an example</i>
  <input type="text" placeholder="zip" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Check this out OP - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6384527/7226958
It's pretty much the same situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example)

```js
var zones = [
  {
  "zone": "one",
  "zipcodes": ["69122", "69125", "69128","69129"]
 },
 {
  "zone": "two",
  "zipcodes": ["67515", "67516", "67518", "67521"]
 }
];

$(function() {
  $('#userZip').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userZip = $('input[type="text"]').val();
    // find the first zone with the userZip inside its zipcodes list
    var zone = zones.find(function(zone) {
      return zone.zipcodes.indexOf(userZip) > -1;
    });
    alert("Zone: " + zone.zone);
  });
});
```

```css
i {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="userZip">
  <i>Enter zip code "69122" as an example</i>
  <input type="text" placeholder="zip" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```