# Array.find method alternative in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using the [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example) method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873107/check-if-zip-code-in-input-exists-in-json-and-get-category?noredirect=1#comment74781669_43873107) I asked earlier and I have realized that it is not supported in IE. Is there a jQuery equivalent or even a different Javascript equivalent which is supported in IE?

```js
var zones = [{
    "zone": "one",
    "zipcodes": ["69122", "69125", "69128", "69129"]
  },
  {
    "zone": "two",
    "zipcodes": ["67515", "67516", "67518", "67521"]
  }
];

$(function() {
  $('#userZip').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userZip = $('input[type="text"]').val();
    var zone = zones.find(function(zone) {
      return zone.zipcodes.indexOf(userZip) > -1;
    });
    alert("Zone: " + zone.zone);
  });
});
```

```css
i {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="userZip">
  <i>Enter zip code "69122" as an example</i>
  <input type="text" placeholder="zip" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why not just patch it in legacy browsers? Relying on large libraries for simple compatibility patches doesn't seem like the best approach.

Comment: jQuery is already included in this project for other reasons so it wouldn't be adding anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polyfill:

```
Array.prototype.find = Array.prototype.find || function (callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if (callback(this[i], i)) {
        return this[i];
      }
    }
};
```

If you want a better one, look under the *polyfill* section of the first link youve provided...

Answer (score 1):

IE9+ supports Array.filter if that's good enough?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Obviously you'll potentially get multiple results so will need to just select the first, if that's your intention.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can also use a standard for loop?

```js
var zones = [{
    "zone": "one",
    "zipcodes": ["69122", "69125", "69128", "69129"]
  },
  {
    "zone": "two",
    "zipcodes": ["67515", "67516", "67518", "67521"]
  }
];

function findZone(zns, zip) {
  var zone = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < zns.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < zns[i].zipcodes.length; j++) {
      if (zip === zns[i].zipcodes[j]) {
        zone = zns[i];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return zone;
}

console.log(findZone(zones, "67515"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A function using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#userZip').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userZip = $('input[type="text"]').val();
    var zone = $.grep(zones, function (element, index) {
      if ($.inArray( userZip, element.zipcodes ) > -1) return true;
    });
    alert("Zone: " + zone[0].zone);
  });
});
```

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/p76f1zev/

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.grep` works similar to Array's `find` method in that it operates on Array-Like objects and filters using a provided function.
The result is a new array with only those elements included that pass the test. It also has an optional `invert` argument.

e.g. for your code

```
var filteredZones = $.grep(zones, function(zone) {
  return zone.zipcodes.indexOf(userZip) > -1;
});

if (filteredZones.length) {
  var zone = filteredZones[0];
}
```

You can read more about it here - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/