# Checking multiple JSON properties for String value for chart value input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this JSON and would like to keep a running tab of the type and color of each candy and display it in a pie chart using zingcharts.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Dog",
        "color": "Blue"
    },
    {
        "name": "Dog",
        "color": "Blue"
    },
    {
        "name": "Cat",
        "color": "Yellow"
    }
```

My JSON is coming from a HTTP get request. I can't seem to get my chart to recognize the integer values of `blueDog` and `yellowCat`.  Am I correctly checking each property for these values?

I tried following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384421/check-whether-a-value-exists-in-json-object) but did not have desired results.

```
      var sortedAnimals= [];
      var blueDog = 0;
      var yellowCat = 0;
      $http.get('/sorted-animals').then(function (response) {
                  $scope.sortedAnimals= response.data;
                  for (var i = 0; i < sortedAnimals.length; i++) {
                       sortedAnimals[i] = sortedAnimals[i];
                       if (sortedAnimals[i].name == "dog" && sortedAnimals[i].color == "blue") {
                            blueDog++;
                       }
                       if (sortedAnimals[i].name == "cat" && sortedAnimals[i].color == "yellow") {
                                yellowCat++;
                       }
                  }
                    $scope.myJson = {
                      type: "pie",
                      title: {
                        textAlign: 'center',
                        text: "My title"
                      },
                      plot: {
                        slice: 50 //to make a donut
                      },
                      series: [{
                        values: [blueDog]
                      },
                      series: [{
                        values: [yellowCat]
                      }]
                    };


            },
                  function (error) {
                       console.log(error);
             });
```

Comment: You can’t have two identical property names in the same object.  The object is $scope.myJson and the duplicate property name is series.  (but from the missing `]` that might be a typo?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look inside your for loop --

```
for (var i = 0; i < sortedAnimals.length; i++) {
                   sortedAnimals[i] = sortedAnimals[i];
                   if (sortedAnimals[i].name == "dog" && sortedAnimals[i].color == "blue") {
                        blueDog++;
                   }
                   if (sortedAnimals[i].name == "cat" && sortedAnimals[i].color == "yellow") {
                            yellowCat++;
                   }
}
```

should be

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.sortedAnimals.length; i++) {
              //I got rid of an unnecessary line here
               if ($scope.sortedAnimals[i].name == "dog" && $scope.sortedAnimals[i].color == "blue") {
                    blueDog++;
               }
               if ($scope.sortedAnimals[i].name == "cat" && $scope.sortedAnimals[i].color == "yellow") {
                        yellowCat++;
               }
}
```

You basically just dropped the $scope but needed to keep it.

If you wanted to have a `sortedAnimals` not on $scope, you'd need to assign as:

`var sortedAnimals = $scope.sortedAnimals`

Comment: thanks! that worked! and made yours the answer for the $scope explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `sortedAnimals` to `$scope.sortedAnimals`:

```
$scope.sortedAnimals = response.data;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.sortedAnimals.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.sortedAnimals[i].name == "dog" && $scope.sortedAnimals[i].color == "blue") {
    blueDog++;
  }
  if ($scope.sortedAnimals[i].name == "cat" && $scope.sortedAnimals[i].color == "yellow") {
    yellowCat++;
  }
}
```